# Article>p+time - too short for article or not?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Im writing a markup for : 
 [image]

Would it be correct to present every tweet like an article or its too short and I should use ul or something else?

```
<section>
    <h1>Recent tweets</h1>
    <article>
        <p>I'm looking...</p>
        <time>3 day ago</time>
    </article>
    <article>
        <p>@mediatemple will ...</p>
        <time>6 days ago</time>
    </article>
    <article>
        <p>Corpora Business</p>
        <time>10 days ago</time>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: If you believe that a tweet can be accurately described as an 'article', then use `article` (my own thought is that it can't, and is perhaps a synopsis or some form of comment on a longer-form article). Otherwise use a different element such as, as you mention, an `li` within a `ul` or `ol`. But it really doesn't matter, I don't think there's a minimum-length requirement for an `article`, and if there were I suspect it would be 'wrong' in many, many cases.

Comment: Perhaps of interest, [recent discussion about article on Public HTML](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2013Jan/0109.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really doesn't matter. The WHATWG is still pretty vague about it. My issue is with the h1. Is this the only thing on the page? Is the page title also 'Recent Tweets'? If so you're fine. But I get the sense this is like a plug-in on a larger page. If so, consider using a lower level tag, for semantic/accessibility reasons.

Comment: Yes, for accessibility reasons it *might* be better to use the calculated heading level (but it's not that clear, as e.g. a certain JAWS version only works with the "`h1` everywhere" approach). However, *semantically* it is correct to use `h1` here, too. Both ways are possible. It depends on your users which way to go. Using `h1` for all sectioning elements has the benefit that you can move the sections freely without having to adjust the heading level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each microblogging entry should be an `article`, as it matches the [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element):

> The `article` element represents a **self-contained composition** in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, **independently distributable or reusable**, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other **independent item of content**.

You could list them in a `ul`/ (or, depending on the context, `ol`) too, if needed/appropriate:

```
<section>
  <h1>Recent tweets</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><article>…</article></li>
    <li><article>…</article></li>
    <li><article>…</article></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

If you'd want to include metadata (like the author name), the `footer` element should be used. That's where your `time` element should be placed, too. If the author name would be linked to a profile where contacting the author is possible, the `address` element should be used (as it is associated with the `article` and not the whole page, which is another reason to use the `article` element for micro-blogging entries).

```
<article>
  <p>…</p>
  <footer>
    <time>…</time>
  </footer>
</article>
```

Comment: This a ridiculous answer -1

Comment: @CharlieTuna: And why do you think that? I can’t clear up doubts if you don’t provide arguments.